# Change the Opening Window in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I am making an application, but silly me I made the main application in the Main Window, but I need to make an opening screen with a start button which opens the main application, any help?

Comment: you know you can change your startup page from app.xaml right? As for the rest of your question, Add a new window to your project(Just modify "StartupUri=MainWindow.xaml" in app.xaml to the new Window. Default name will be Window1.xaml) add a button to it and on the click handler create MainWindow and call Show()

Comment: Viv is right. you also also can do it via App.xaml.cs if you want to make it dynamic.